# Cytoscape : Graph is not displayed when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cytoscape.js

I have incorporated a cytoscape graph into a div which has an initial status of `{display:none}`.

When the div is shown `($('div#id').show())`, the graph is not displayed unless the user resizes the browser window.

I looked into the css with the js console, and realized the initial css of the canvas is such that : `width: 0px; height: 0px`.

It is only when the browser window is resized that the canvas inherits #cy's width and height:

Initial CSS status :

```
<div id="cy">
    <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px;">**<canvas data-id="layer0-selectbox" width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></canvas>...
```

CSS status when browser window is resized:

```
 <div id="cy"><div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 560px; height: 420px;"><canvas data-id="layer0-selectbox" width="560" height="420" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5; **width: 560px; height: 420px;"**>...
```

Any idea why this happens? Could you help me to fix this?

Comment: Give the canvas a width and height; since it's `display: none` initially, those values should still be there when the `<div>` is set to show again.

Comment: @stealthyninja Thanks for your answer. I realised that the global canvas inherites the correct size properties. But there is a series of embeded canvas elements that don't:  <canvas data-id="layer0-selectbox" width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute; z-index: 5; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></canvas>

Answer (score 2):

It is unfortunate that given how the DOM works, you can not (solely) use `display: none` in this case.

`display: none` messes with dimensions detection, and so you will need to either

(1) use another CSS property like `visibility: hidden` or offpage absolute positioning, or

(2) call [`cy.resize()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/viewport-manipulation/cy.resize) explicitly upon showing the graph.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. "Visibility: hidden" works fine! A comment about cy.resize(). I tryed it as well and the nodes and edges were actually displayed ( \o/ ) but without positionning or layout (all nodes were drawn at coordinates x:0, y:0). Any idea which command might be added to solve this? Best regards.